# Should I use a parallel or serial connection?

Tags: serial, parallel

I need to split one power cord from the wall socket to power three 20w lamps.

Should I use a parallel, or a serial connection?

Follow up question: In which ever case, where can I find some guidelines for how to proceed?

Comment: About electricity, not electronics. Will be closed.

Comment: @Brian Is there a place where questions like this are on topic? As far as I know, there's no Stack Exchange for electricity.

Comment: Its such a simple question it's almost insulting to ask for some of the professionals on the site since its kind of expected that you have some kind of circuit theory background. A bit of searching on google  of serial vs parallel should give you the answer. To answer your question: if you put three 20W lamp in serial it will be like one 60W lamp, if you put them in parallel it will be like one 20/3 or 6.67W lamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the 20W lamps are designed to operate at the wall socket voltage then you will want to wire the lamps in parallel connection.

Some guidelines.

- Make sure you appreciate that messing with AC wall power can be dangerous.
- Make sure the power cord is not plugged in when you are wiring the circuit.
- Make sure all the connections are properly insulated and secured before attempting to power up the circuit.
- Do use the proper type of socket for the 20W lamps that have proper terminals to take the attachment of the wires.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel. If you place the lamps in series each will only get 1/3 of the mains voltage, and give less than 1/10th of the rated light level. (Theoretically 1/9th, because power is proportional to voltage squared, but at lower voltages the filament will be less hot, meaning emitting less light.

If you place the lamps in parallel each will get the required mains voltage.